# Change variable name in xtable

Tags: r, sweave, xtable

I want to change the name of the variable I'm tabulating using `xtable()` in Sweave. I suppose that it's trivial, but I can't find out how to do it. Here's an example: I want to edit "conv" (it is the name of the variable I'm tabulating) and write whatever I want.

The code I'm using to produce it:

```
<<results=tex,echo=FALSE>>=
tab<-prop.table(table(conv))*100
print(xtable(tab,
             caption="Conversion a Premium (en tanto por ciento)",
             label="table:Conversion",
             digits=2),latex.environments = "center"
      )
@
```

The result:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have always found it easiest to pass a `matrix` to `xtable`; the options in declaring a `matrix` include `dimnames`, which makes it easy to print out whatever you'd like:

```
print(xtable(matrix(tab,dimnames=list(names(tab),"Whatever You'd Like")),
             caption="Conversion a Premium (en tanto por ciento)",
             label="table:Conversion",
             digits=2),latex.environments = "center"
)
```

Produces:

```
% latex table generated in R 3.2.1 by xtable 1.7-4 package
% Mon Aug 17 12:01:18 2015
\begin{table}[ht]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{rr}
  \hline
 & Whatever You'd Like \\ 
  \hline
No se Convierte & 99.20 \\ 
  Se Convierte & 0.80 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\caption{Conversion a Premium (en tanto por ciento)} 
\label{table:Conversion}
\end{table}
```

Comment: Great! @MichaelChirico But now I'm receiving an error when the table is crossed with another variable... It says: The length of dimnames[1] is not equal to the extension of the array.

Comment: when you cross with another variable, you should probably use `rownames` and `colnames`.

Comment: Thank you for your help!

Comment: Actually, with `table(x,y)`, the row and column names should already be the levels of `x` and `y`, respectively; you only need to use the `dimnames` approach if you want to change the labelling.

Answer (score 0):

You can use dnn inside table and that fix it.

```
tab <- prop.table(table(conv, dnn = "Whatever you want"))*100
```